# SSL handshake failed when trying to add remote GitLab account in GitAhead under openSUSE Leap 15

Tags: linux, opensuse, gitahead

I successfully added remote (private) GitLab account under Windows 10 in GitAhead but under a Linux openSUSE Leap 15 I got "Connection failed: SSL handshake failed".

Note that I can clone, pull, fetch, commit, push in repositories from repositories in the GitLab I want to add, I also tried to reset SSH handshake with:

```
$ ssh-keygen -R gitlab.mydomain.net
# Host gitlab.mydomain.net found: line 31
/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts updated.
Original contents retained as /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts.old
$ ssh git@gitlab.mydomain.net
The authenticity of host 'gitlab.mydomain.net (<IP>)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:**************.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'gitlab.mydomain.net,<IP>' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Welcome to GitLab, @UserName!
Connection to gitlab.mydomain.net closed.
```

But it still does not work, anyone knows if there is something to configure to allow it under Linux ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a starter, check the rights on directories on the server-side. The home-dir as well as the .ssh-dir should be treated with `chmod 700`. The same is true for the key files.

You should aim for a passwordless login on your server. As soon as this works, GitAhead should be fine. If you have a Git-Shell in your server-side `/etc/passwd`, replace it by `/bin/sh` for the sake of sending your pubkey: On the client, enter `ssh-copy-id -i yourprivatekeyfile somerandomgituser@ipofyourgitserver`. After that, if successful, you can reset the `/etc/passwd` line back to the Git-Shell.